# Executing actions while app is in killed / inactive state

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Is there any way to execute an action while app is in inactive or killed state?

I found this usecase while handling remote notifications when app is in inactive/ killed state.I want to execute a [react-native-shortcut-badger](https://github.com/nguquen/react-native-shortcut-badger) function to set a badge number when a remote notification is received.

Comment: Which OS / platform?

Comment: @deLock both not working

Comment: No, I meant that your post had not tags and did not contain any name of any operating system (e.g. "Android") or language/platform (e.g. web, JavaScript), etc. Now I can see it's tagged.

Comment: @deLock its for react-native